# Why some Attribute exist on "productslp" but not "products" table in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Why product `attribute` defined in `Product` itemtype not show in `products` table but `productslp` table ?

Comment: @Trinh - Could please give any attribute name which you are not able to find in products table.

Comment: I commended below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*lp files for localization. Your attribute has localized option.

Comment: So, Localized attributes defined on items file will be stored on (productslp) = tablename+lp. Correct?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`PRODUCTSLP` is lang table for Product Item, If any localized attributes defines in item those data will be stored against LP table. This table creation and join will be done by hybris internally.

Note : you can find each attribute with prefix `p_` in respective table.
`name` will store in `p_name`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

deployment element used for item type save table name on db. localized value in type attribute meaning of this attribute need localization by language. So hybris create another table with suffix lp automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

example:p_name, p_description . In cores-item.xml file:

```
 <itemtype code="Product"
              extends="GenericItem"
              jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.jalo.product.Product"
              autocreate="true"
              generate="true">
        <deployment table="Products" typecode="1" propertytable="ProductProps"/>
        <attributes>
            <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="code" type="java.lang.String" generate="true">
                <persistence type="property"/>
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" initial="true" optional="false" unique="true"/>
                <custom-properties>
                    <property name="hmcIndexField">
                        <value>"thefield"</value>
                    </property>
                </custom-properties>
            </attribute>
            <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="name" type="localized:java.lang.String">
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
                <persistence type="property"/>
                <custom-properties>
                    <property name="hmcIndexField">
                        <value>"thefield"</value>
                    </property>
                </custom-properties>
            </attribute>
            <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="unit" type="Unit" generate="true">
                <persistence type="property"/>
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
            </attribute>
            <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="description" type="localized:java.lang.String">
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
                <persistence type="property">
                    <columntype database="oracle">
                        <value>CLOB</value>
                    </columntype>
                    <columntype database="sap">
                        <value>NCLOB</value>
                    </columntype>
                    <columntype>
                        <value>HYBRIS.LONG_STRING</value>
                    </columntype>
                </persistence>
                <custom-properties>
                    <property name="hmcIndexField">
                        <value>"thefield"</value>
                    </property>
                </custom-properties>
            </attribute>
            <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="thumbnail" type="Media">
                <persistence type="property"/>
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
            </attribute>
            <attribute autocreate="true" qualifier="picture" type="Media">
                <persistence type="property"/>
                <modifiers read="true" write="true" search="true" optional="true"/>
            </attribute>
        </attributes>
        <indexes>
            <index name="Product_Code">
                <key attribute="code"/>
            </index>
        </indexes>
    </itemtype>
```

I see attributes defined obove.but not see it in table products. note:

```
<deployment table="Products"...>
```

What is meaning?

Comment: please edit your question or ask new question. stackoverflow not working look like forums.